# EC2 and Mailgun DNS setting

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I'll preface this by saying I'm very much a newbie when it comes to servers, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to configure an Amazon EC2 instance to allow me to send e-mail through Mailgun but I can't figure out where to enter the DNS records that Mailgun require for sending e-mail.

Evey example I've found on DNS settings and EC2 in general seem to assume that I have a domain registered with Amazon or some other provider that I want to point to the EC2 instance, while I just use an Elastic IP address to access my instance.

So, is there some way I can effectively get Mailgun and my EC2 instance working together without registering a separate domain? And if so, where do I enter the DNS records?

Comment: Wherever your DNS is hosted is where you need to modify the records.  Amazon can host them on Route53 if you choose to go that way.

Comment: @Optichip: Ok, but isn't my elastic ip (ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com) a domain and consequently I should be able to modify the DNS records for that domain somewhere? Or can I somehow use Route 53 to modify the DNS records for the domain for my elastic ip? I tried creating a hosted zone in Route 53 to route the domain to itself (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html) but the UI complained that I had entered an invalid value for the IPv4 address.

Comment: amazonaws.com is not YOUR domain, it's someone elses you are unable to modify their domain, if you're going to send mail, you need your own identity ie your own domain.  There are free ones, there are cheap ones, there are all kinds.  If you are not looking to spend money I would suggest looking into something like .tk free domains.

Comment: @Optichip: Ok, thanks, it wasn't obvious from any of the docs that I found that I should not be able to modify my EC2 instance to work with a 3rd party e-mail service. Thanks for the help and for your patience.

Comment: No problem, as long as you have a domain to point it at it should work fine.  Read up on SPF (Sender policy framework) to ensure that all of your e-mail gets to its final destination.